# How do I create padded batches in Tensorflow for tf.train.SequenceExample data using the DataSet API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm, tensorflow-datasets

For training an **LSTM model** in **Tensorflow**, I have structured my data into a **tf.train.SequenceExample** format and stored it into a **TFRecord file**. I would now like to use the new DataSet API to **generate padded batches for training**. In [the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets) there is an example for using padded_batch, but for my data I can't figure out what the value of *padded_shapes* should be.

For reading the TFrecord file into the batches I have written the following Python code:

```
import math
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import struct
import sys
import array

if(len(sys.argv) != 2):
  print "Usage: createbatches.py [RFRecord file]"
  sys.exit(0)


vectorSize = 40
inFile = sys.argv[1]

def parse_function_dataset(example_proto):
  sequence_features = {
      'inputs': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[vectorSize],
                                           dtype=tf.float32),
      'labels': tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature(shape=[],
                                           dtype=tf.int64)}

  _, sequence = tf.parse_single_sequence_example(example_proto, sequence_features=sequence_features)

  length = tf.shape(sequence['inputs'])[0]
  return sequence['inputs'], sequence['labels']

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

filenames = tf.placeholder(tf.string, shape=[None])
dataset = tf.contrib.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames)
dataset = dataset.map(parse_function_dataset)
# dataset = dataset.batch(1)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(4, padded_shapes=[None])
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

batch = iterator.get_next()

# Initialize `iterator` with training data.
training_filenames = [inFile]
sess.run(iterator.initializer, feed_dict={filenames: training_filenames})

print(sess.run(batch))
```

The code works well if I use `dataset = dataset.batch(1)` (no padding needed in that case), but when I use the `padded_batch` variant, I get the following error:

> TypeError: If shallow structure is a sequence, input must also be a
>   sequence. Input has type: .

Can you help me figuring out what I should pass for the *padded_shapes* parameter?

(I know there is lots of example code using threading and queues for this, but I'd rather use the new DataSet API for this project)

Comment: Thanks Marijn! Your questions helped me a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to pass a tuple of shapes.
In your case you should pass

```
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(4, padded_shapes=([vectorSize],[None]))
```

or try

```
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(4, padded_shapes=([None],[None]))
```

Check this [code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/d236d19f7753ae23f91d794701efa70ace1629da/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py#L427) for more details. I had to debug this method to figure out why it wasn't working for me.

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot of sense. The following worked for my example: `padded_shapes=([None,vectorSize],[None])`. The first tensor is a list of vectors with dimension vectorSize and the second is a list with integer labels.

Comment: Just as complement, `padded_shapes` is sensitive to the type of the nested struct (if the dataset return a tuple, padded_shapes should be a tuple too and not a list)

Answer (score 3):

If your current `Dataset` object contains a tuple, you can also to specify the shape of each padded element.

For example, I have a `(same_sized_images, Labels)` dataset and each label has different length but same rank.

```
def process_label(resized_img, label):
    # Perfrom some tensor transformations
    # ......

    return resized_img, label

dataset = dataset.map(process_label)
dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, 
                               padded_shapes=([None, None, 3], 
                                              [None, None]))  # my label has rank 2
```

Comment: Why did you use 3 for third image dimension instead of None?

Answer (score 1):

You may need to get help from the dataset output shapes:

```
padded_shapes = dataset.output_shapes
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware of not passing a tuple of tuples. That gives a very vague error of "cannot convert value None to type Nonetype".

So correct:
`padded_shapes = ([None, None], [None])`

INCORRECT:
`padded_shapes = ((None, None), (None))`