# Getting free text features into Tensorflow Canned Estimators with Dataset API via feature_columns

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I'm trying to build a model that gives `reddit_score = f('subreddit','comment')`

Mainly this is as an example i can then build on for a work project.

My code is [here](https://github.com/andrewm4894/my-google-cloudml-tensorflow-examples/tree/master/reddit_score).

My problem is that i see that canned estimators e.g. [DNNLinearCombinedRegressor](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/learn/DNNLinearCombinedRegressor) must have feature_columns that are part of `FeatureColumn` class.

I have my vocab file and know that if i was to just limit to the first word of a comment i could just do something like

```
tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file(
        key='comment',
        vocabulary_file='{}/vocab.csv'.format(INPUT_DIR)
        )
```

But if i'm passing in say first 10 words from a comment then i'm not sure how to go from a string like `"this is a pre padded 10 word comment xyzpadxyz xyzpadxyz"` to a `feature_column` such that i can then build an embedding to pass to the `deep` features in a wide and deep model.

It seems like it must be something really obvious or simple but can't for life of me find any existing examples with this particular set up (canned wide and deep, dataset api, and a mix of features e.g subreddit and a raw text feature like comment).

I was even thinking about doing the vocab integer lookup myself such that the `comment` feature i pass in would be something like [23,45,67,12,1,345,7,99,999,999] and then maybe i could get it in via numeric_feature with a shape and then from there do something with it. But this feels a bit odd.

Comment: i'm thinking maybe i could make a function to split the comments feature into a comments_words type feature as part of the read_dataset() function perhaps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding answer as per approach from the post @Lak did, but adapted a little for dataset api.

```
# Create an input function reading a file using the Dataset API
# Then provide the results to the Estimator API
def read_dataset(prefix, mode, batch_size):

    def _input_fn():

        def decode_csv(value_column):

            columns = tf.decode_csv(value_column, field_delim='|', record_defaults=DEFAULTS)
            features = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS, columns))

            features['comment_words'] = tf.string_split([features['comment']])
            features['comment_words'] = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(features['comment_words'], default_value=PADWORD)
            features['comment_padding'] = tf.constant([[0,0],[0,MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH]])
            features['comment_padded'] = tf.pad(features['comment_words'], features['comment_padding'])
            features['comment_sliced'] = tf.slice(features['comment_padded'], [0,0], [-1, MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH])
            features['comment_words'] = tf.pad(features['comment_sliced'], features['comment_padding'])
            features['comment_words'] = tf.slice(features['comment_words'],[0,0],[-1,MAX_DOCUMENT_LENGTH])

            features.pop('comment_padding')
            features.pop('comment_padded')
            features.pop('comment_sliced')

            label = features.pop(LABEL_COLUMN)

            return features, label

        # Use prefix to create file path
        file_path = '{}/{}*{}*'.format(INPUT_DIR, prefix, PATTERN)

        # Create list of files that match pattern
        file_list = tf.gfile.Glob(file_path)

        # Create dataset from file list
        dataset = (tf.data.TextLineDataset(file_list)  # Read text file
                    .map(decode_csv))  # Transform each elem by applying decode_csv fn

        tf.logging.info("...dataset.output_types={}".format(dataset.output_types))
        tf.logging.info("...dataset.output_shapes={}".format(dataset.output_shapes))

        if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:

            num_epochs = None # indefinitely
            dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = 10 * batch_size)

        else:

            num_epochs = 1 # end-of-input after this

        dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs).batch(batch_size)

        return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()

    return _input_fn
```

Then in below function we can reference the field we made as part of `decode_csv()` :

```
# Define feature columns
def get_wide_deep():

    EMBEDDING_SIZE = 10

    # Define column types
    subreddit = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('subreddit', ['news', 'ireland', 'pics'])

    comment_embeds = tf.feature_column.embedding_column(
        categorical_column = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_file(
            key='comment_words',
            vocabulary_file='{}/vocab.csv-00000-of-00001'.format(INPUT_DIR),
            vocabulary_size=100
            ),
        dimension = EMBEDDING_SIZE
        )

    # Sparse columns are wide, have a linear relationship with the output
    wide = [ subreddit ]

    # Continuous columns are deep, have a complex relationship with the output
    deep = [ comment_embeds ]

    return wide, deep
```

Comment: above works so long as you have same number of words in each feature (which was fine for my use case). If not then i believe would need to use dataset.padded_batch see relevant question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45955241/how-do-i-create-padded-batches-in-tensorflow-for-tf-train-sequenceexample-data-u

Answer (score 2):

You could use tf.string_split(), then do tf.slice() to slice it, taking care to tf.pad() the strings with zeros first. Look at the title preprocessing operations in:
 https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-do-text-classification-using-tensorflow-word-embeddings-and-cnn-edae13b3e575

Once you have the words, then you can create ten feature columns

Comment: hmm i'm getting ` Cannot batch tensors with different shapes in component 1. First element had shape [1,11] and element 1 had shape [1,6]` am guessing is dues to variable len comments. Any idea if i can handle this in my decode_csv() or would need to do it in the raw data itself?